# spring security authentication only one field(IP address of user)

Tags: spring-security

I have  users in my db and each user has IP address. I must give access to site only users whose IP address exist in my db. Users not have login and password. They have phone number, id, details and IP address. When user open web page I detect his IP address, faind in db and I give access or deny access. If access successfully I need save this user to session.

Can I use spring security for this?

When I tried use spring security I saw that need login and password for it. But my user not have login and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but I am unsure whether you should.

First, for common use cases, using IP based authentication is really poor security practice: only one element, and any admin of a single machine on the network can change its IP address and pretend to be someone else.

Assuming you have a real reason to do that, Spring security can easily to it. You will have to setup a custom authentication processing filter that would use the IP address to build a valid `Authentication`. It could derive from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` or `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`.

The filter could do the heavy job and directly put a fully authenticated authentication token in the `SecurityContext` obtained from the static methods of the `SecurityContextHolder` class. But the *Spring Security way* would be to only put a `WebAuthenticationDetails` in a custom `Authentication` token, pass it to the `AuthenticationManager` and let a custom `AuthenticationProvider` builds the fully authenticated `Authentication`.